# How can I both add a Style and a Template to a Button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, rounded-corners, datatrigger, cornerradius

How can I both add a Style and a Template to a Button?

I have a Style with a DataTrigger that sets the background color of the Button to either Gray (if disabled) or Blue (if enabled).

I also have a ControlTemplate that sets the CornerRadius to give it some rounded corners.

Each of those two works individually. But when I add them both to the Button, the ControlTemplate takes precedence, and the Style with the DataTrigger is lost. I end up seeing a button with no border, and no background.

How can I accomplish both of these tasks together?

```
<Button Grid.Row="4" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsSubmitButtonEnabled.Value}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18px" Height="36">

    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSubmitButtonEnabled.Value}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border CornerRadius="20">
                <TextBlock Text="Submit"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="16">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>

</Button>
```

Comment: The ControlTemplate does not use the Background property of the Button. Add `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` to the Border.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. Could you please add that as an Answer, that I may mark it?